# ProgressDialog become unresponsive

Tags: android, android-layout, progressdialog

I have used ProgressDialog in Android application.
I have a login, password and Loginbtn in a main form, when i login, i move to next screen, the login is on the bases of internet and webdomain, means upon login it sends request to online server having php file, which returns true or false, and it then moves to next screen. I want to use ProcessDialog unless it obtains true or false from server, and if it gets false the wheel should stop processing and it should show the message that invalid username or password, and if it gets true, after getting true it should end the process dialog and move to the next screen, right now ProcessDialog is working but when we click, i just start dialog to work, and then automatically intent moves to the next screen, but if we press back button, it still shows process dialog rotating. i just want to use processDialog in a correct way.
My code is

```
//start
 progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DomainDownManagerActivity.this);
             progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
             progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
             progressDialog.show();
             progressDialog.setProgress(100);

> if (v==true){ 
//v has true 
 Intent intent = new Intent(DomainDownManagerActivity.this,MainPanelActivity.class);

startActivity(intent);

    }

    else{
    //set label of invalid user or pass
    }
```

Image attached
[image]

Comment: Who is rating me negative? If you dont have answer then dont rate negative ok!!!

Comment: http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/progressBarExample.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// write this line  `new SomeTask(0).execute();`  in your loginBtn.onCLick 
/** Inner class for implementing progress bar before fetching data **/

  private class SomeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> 
    {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(yourActivityClass.this);
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {

        Dialog.setMessage("loading...");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {


           //Task for doing something 
 //   get data from php server if true then return

            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
        {



       if(result==0)
            {
//do some thing if true
Intent intent = new Intent(DomainDownManagerActivity.this,MainPanelActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
            }

    // after completed finished the progressbar
            Dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```